# How To Edit/Add/Delete/Rename Files/Folders In Ubuntu Server Using FileZilla?

Tags: server, windows-7, permissions, ftp, filezilla

I am using "**UbuntuServer13.10**" on my server and "**Windows7-SP1**" On my PC. Now I want to edit, add, delete, rename my files and folders in server using FTP. For this purpose, I installed "**FileZilla 3.7.4.1 win32**" in my PC and then try to connect my server though using it. I added my internal server IP(sftp://192.168.1.99) and my username(Ubuntu username not root) and password and added Port22. After this I was able to see my server files on FileZilla but not able to edit, add, delete, rename my files and folders in server using FileZilla.

When I try to add files then get "*open for write: permission denied*" and when try to delete file get "*permission denied*". Now my main question is that "**How To Edit/Add/Delete/Rename Files/Folders In Ubuntu Server Using FileZilla?**". Waiting for your reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried executing the command **ls -l** on the folder tou want to read/write on? The user you connect with might not have enough rights. This is usually the case when another user has created the files you want to access.

While **ls -l** lets you check who is the owner of the file/directory you want to access, to change permissions you can use `chmod` (more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod))

EDIT:
If you want to manage the access right to a specific folder for a single user, you will have to either:

- Create the folder so that the user is the owner, and thus has all rights on it
- Make sure the owner of the folder allowed the user to access it

To do that, you could for instance change the ownership of the folder and atribute it to the user. That way, you could manage access rights the way you want.
Juste type in `sudo chown -R user /var/www/site1`. This recursivelly (thanks to -R) attributes ownership to user.

For a bonus, you could `chmod 500 /var/www/site1` so that no-one except user (and root, obviously) could read/write on the folder

NB: 
The 5 used as an argument for chmod means you grant read & write permission. To grant read, write & execute permission, use 7. To grant none use 0.
The first number represent the permission for the owner, the second number represent the permission for the group, and the third represent the permission for the other users. Refer to the link provided if you need more info

NB2:
To check your ownership/permission on a file or a folder, type `ls -l /my/folder`, and you should get something like this :

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 65 Feb 11 15:08 index.html
     |         |     |
  permissions  |     |
             owner   group
```

Comment: I just started it and I did nothing. Now I want to control my all files and folders in "var/WWW/..." Using FileZilla. Can you tell me completely that what to do to get control over the main folder.

I think that "root" is the owner of file because I tried to edit  edit, add, delete, rename my files and folders directly in my server through user but I was unable then I login via root then will able to do all action.

Comment: ok then if you want your /var/www/ folder to be read and written to by all users, type as root (or use sudo) : `chmod 555 /var/WWW/`. If you want to read existing files, use `chmod 555 /var/WWW/*`. Please note that it is quite unsafe as it allows r/w permission for any user connecting to your server. If your server contains data you need to protect, you might want to play a bit with permissions

Comment: Thanks for replying me and also mentioning the after effects. So what you think is the best for me? I also want to keep me server secure. I currently have only one user like "user1". Is this possible to make a folder like "/var/www/site1" and allow only "user1" to edit, add, delete, rename my files and folders in it?

Comment: I will update my answer to address your comment

Comment: Thanks to update your answer. I did as you said and I used **user@server:~$ sudo mkdir /var/www/site1** and  got my folder. Now in next step I wrote **user@server:~$ chmod 700 /var/www/site1** and got **chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/www/site1’: Operation not permitted**. What to do know?

Comment: When you don't have permission, you can always use `sudo`. Note that you should do this only if you know what you are doing, as `sudo` will execute a command with root privileges, even if it may harm your computer. In this case, changing permissions isn't really dangerous, so you're safe. Try `sudo` before your `chmod`, you shouldn't get the error anymore. Could you paste the result of `ls -l /var/www/` though ?

Comment: I again typed **user@server:~$ sudo chmod 700 /var/www/site1** and entered my password and there was no error in terminal but when I tried to open folder in my server, I got **The location could not be displayed. You don't have the permissions necessary to view the content of "site1"**. But last night it was opening without any error. Now after adding this code in terminal, I got error. Its also not opening in FileZilla in my pc even to view folder content.

Comment: Here is the result after adding your code...

-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     65 Feb 11 15:08 check.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 hassan hassan  806 Mar 25 12:39 index.html
drwx------ 2 root   root   4096 Mar 25 21:23 site1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     20 Feb 12 07:18 textphp.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     20 Feb 12 07:18 textphp.php~

Comment: oooh, ok, I see what I told you was partly wrong (I answer from my workplace, and I don't have a linux to test if what I tell you is right). The problem here is that user is not the owner of the folder, but root is as you used `sudo`. You need to use `chown` in order to change ownership. I'll update my answer again ;)

Comment: Its Ok. No need to hurry. Give me solution easily when you will be free. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Now I am able to edit, add, delete, rename my files and folders directly in my server's folder through FileZilla ifrom PC loggin via my username after using `sudo chown -R user /var/www/site1`. Now I uploaded a file "index.html" and when I trioed to open it in my browser using internal IP, I got **Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /site1/index.html on this server.** I am able to view "/var/www/index.html" in browser but not "/var/www/site1/index.html". How to open this in browser?

Comment: Are you trying to acces your page from outside of your server (i.e. from your windows PC) ? If so, it is normal. Due to your `chmod 700` on the folder `/var/www/site1`, only `user` can access its content. To correct this, you should `chmod 777 /var/www/site1`. However, if you still want some files to be access-protected, you could for instance create a folder `/var/www/site1/private` and `chmod 700` it after making sure `user` is the owner of the folder.

Comment: Thanks for solving this issue too. Now my all problems are now solved but I have a question in advance. If I will create any folder in "site1", Will that be in my(user1) controll automatically as user1 now have full controll on "site1" folder? And if iI want to make any folder private then  I will run `user@server:~$ sudo chmod 700 /var/www/site1/privateFolder` on it?

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) ! Please accept the answer if your problem is solved. Concerning your remarks, any folder/file created in your `/var/www/site1` will inherit permission, i.e. you will have full control on it if you create it as `user`. If you want to change permission to make it private, use `chmod` as you did in your exemple. Note that if you create content using `sudo`, wich you may need sometimes, you might need to use `chown` as previously done to change ownership & rights. Try and experiment around to see what permissions is best suited to each file.

Comment: Sure, I will create a private folder in it and will apply the `chmod 700` to it only to keep this folder secure. Anyway Thanks for helping me out...

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is connecting with FTP over SSH (that's what SFTP is). So you are only able to do the operations that your user is permitted to do over SSH - if your user doesn't own or doesn't belong to a group that has write permissions on the files you are trying to edit or the folders you are trying to create files in, you won't be able to do this over SFTP (since you're not allowed to over SSH).

You can use `ls -alh` for example, to check what group those files and folders belong to and, if the group has **write** permissions over those files and folders, than add your user to that group and you should be good to go (over SFTP also).

Comment: I think that "root" is the owner of file because I tried to edit edit, add, delete, rename my files and folders directly in my server through user but I was unable then I login via root then will able to do all action. Can I connect "FileZilla" via "root" instead of my "username" so I think that after this I will be able to edit, add, delete, rename my files and folders. Am I right then how to connect via "root"