# How to edit django files on a running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS server

Tags: 18.04, server, python, filezilla

I am having an issue with an Ubuntu server.

Actually, I was trying to edit a Django project on an ubuntu server but was unable to reflect the changes on the website.

After lots of searching, I realized that I am doing something wrong that's why changes are not visible. I believe the typical edit and save system doesn't work on ubuntu. So my question is how do I make changes to work on a live server?

**Example:**

I want to comment out a section that is responsible for sending emails, whenever I comment out the code block, it still sends the emails.

**The setup I used:**

I have logged into the server using FileZilla(Windows 10) and just used the `root username and password` for logging in, after that, I can see the file list just went to `home>project>app` and edited a .py file, saved the file and `FileZilla` asked to transfer the file I clicked yes, after that, no result on the website.

**Server:**

The server is a digital ocean droplet, I found out that the ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`.

Someone suggested that running migrate command on the server will fix the issue, but I am afraid that if I run migrate command it might crash the server cause it is working fine till now and I cannot handle the server crash.

Strange thing is, the changes I made on .HTML files are visible but the changes that I made on .py files didn't work.

So please help me here or guide me on the right path.

Thank you so much.

[How To Edit/Add/Delete/Rename Files/Folders In Ubuntu Server Using FileZilla?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438890/how-to-edit-add-delete-rename-files-folders-in-ubuntu-server-using-filezilla)
This question didn't helped.

Comment: Have you restarted the server since updating the python files? Django only autoreloads in development mode, pretty sure.

Comment: No, I didn't restart the server.